# Positioning DIVs after resizable()

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using jQuery's resizable(). I want to center an image to the resized div after it's resized. I'm using the `stop: function()` but no success.

This what I've tried. 
But it does not center the div to the resized div. How do I center `#smlD` to `#mainD` when resized?

```
$('#mainD').resizable({
              stop: function (){
                var gpa = ($('#mainD').width() - $('#smlD').width()) / 2;
                    $('#smlD').css({ left: gpa });
              }
        });
```

**EDIT**

css:

```
.inW3{
    position:relative;
    background-color: #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;      
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.innerWrp .inW1 .inW2{
    position: relative;
}

.outerWrp{
    position: absolute;
}
```

html:

```
<div class ="outerWrp">
   <div class ="innerWrp">
      <div class ="inW1">
         <div class ="inW2" id="mainD">
            <div class ="inW3" id ="smlD">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your HTML? Is there any reason you can't maintain center with CSS?

Comment: @Mooseman: thanks. There are multiple DIV which goes as pairs. I'm using css to center them. But once a div is resized it looses it's positioning. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Let the css do the work for you. With `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto` you shouldn't be worried about centering on stop `resizable()`.

Check out your code here [CodePen](http://codepen.io/jotamartins/pen/bNjZeW) working with centering on resize:

```
$('#mainD').resizable();
```